# How can I horizontally center a (long)table, disregarding certain columns?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, longtable

I have a longtable that technically consists of three columns. However, the third column is just a mark (like a *) to the corresponding row (see picture for clarification).
I want LaTeX to center my table horizontally, but I want it to ignore the third column while doing so. In other words: if my table had two rows, it should be regularly centered. If I then add the third row, the table should not shift horizontally.

Is this doable?

[image: Picture of the table I described above.]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c}
    \caption{Caption1}\\
\cline{1-2}
    $\mathbf{\{p,q\}}$&$\mathbf{(V,E,F)}$&~\endfirsthead
    \caption{caption2}\\
\cline{1-2}
    $\mathbf{\{p,q\}}$&$\mathbf{(V,E,F)}$&~\\\cline{1-2}\endhead
\cline{1-2}
$\{3,7\}$&$(36,126,84)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{3,8\}$&$(18,72,48)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{3,9\}$&$(12,54,36)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{3,10\}$&$(9,45,30)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{3,12\}$&$(6,36,24)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{3,15\}$&$(4,30,20)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{3,18\}$&$(3,27,18)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{3,24\}$&$(2,24,16)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{3,42\}$&$(1,21,14)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{4,5\}$&$(24,60,30)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{4,6\}$&$(12,36,18)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{4,7\}$&$(8,28,14)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{4,8\}$&$(6,24,12)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{4,10\}$&$(4,20,10)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{4,12\}$&$(3,18,9)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{4,16\}$&$(2,16,8)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{4,28\}$&$(1,14,7)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{5,4\}$&$(30,60,24)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{5,5\}$&$(12,30,12)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{5,10\}$&$(3,15,6)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{6,4\}$&$(18,36,12)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{6,6\}$&$(6,18,6)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{6,12\}$&$(2,12,4)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{7,3\}$&$(84,126,36)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{7,4\}$&$(14,28,8)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{7,7\}$&$(4,14,4)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{8,3\}$&$(48,72,18)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{8,4\}$&$(12,24,6)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{8,8\}$&$(3,12,3)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{9,3\}$&$(36,54,12)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{9,18\}$&$(1,9,2)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{10,3\}$&$(30,45,9)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{10,4\}$&$(10,20,4)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{10,5\}$&$(6,15,3)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{10,10\}$&$(2,10,2)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{12,3\}$&$(24,36,6)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{12,4\}$&$(9,18,3)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{12,6\}$&$(4,12,2)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{15,3\}$&$(20,30,4)$&\\
\cline{1-2}
$\{16,4\}$&$(8,16,2)$&\\
\hline
$\{16,16\}$&$(1,8,1)$&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{FP}\\
\cline{1-3}
$\{18,3\}$&$(18,27,3)$&\\
\hline
$\{18,9\}$&$(2,9,1)$&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{FP}\\
\cline{1-3}
$\{24,3\}$&$(16,24,2)$&\\
\hline
$\{28,4\}$&$(7,14,1)$&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{FP}\\
\hline
$\{42,3\}$&$(14,21,1)$&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{FP}\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (rude) solution is add empty column on the table left side with width of last column:

[image]
[image]

Slightly simplified code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array, longtable}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{longtable}{>{\hphantom{FP}}c|>{$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$}|c}
    \caption{Caption1}\\
\cline{2-3}
&    \mathbf{\{p,q\}}&\mathbf{(V,E,F)}&~\endfirsthead
    \caption{caption2}\\
\cline{2-3}
&    \mathbf{\{p,q\}}&\mathbf{(V,E,F)}&~\\\cline{2-3}\endhead
\cline{2-3}
&   \{3,7\}&(36,126,84)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{3,8\}&(18,72,48)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{3,9\}&(12,54,36)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{3,10\}&(9,45,30)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{3,12\}&(6,36,24)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{3,15\}&(4,30,20)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{3,18\}&(3,27,18)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{3,24\}&(2,24,16)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{3,42\}&(1,21,14)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{4,5\}&(24,60,30)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{4,6\}&(12,36,18)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{4,7\}&(8,28,14)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{4,8\}&(6,24,12)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{4,10\}&(4,20,10)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{4,12\}&(3,18,9)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{4,16\}&(2,16,8)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{4,28\}&(1,14,7)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{5,4\}&(30,60,24)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{5,5\}&(12,30,12)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{5,10\}&(3,15,6)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{6,4\}&(18,36,12)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{6,6\}&(6,18,6)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{6,12\}&(2,12,4)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{7,3\}&(84,126,36)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{7,4\}&(14,28,8)&\\
   \cline{2-3}
&   \{7,7\}&(4,14,4)&\\
   \cline{2-3}
&   \{8,3\}&(48,72,18)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{8,4\}&(12,24,6)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{8,8\}&(3,12,3)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{9,3\}&(36,54,12)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{9,18\}&(1,9,2)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{10,3\}&(30,45,9)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{10,4\}&(10,20,4)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{10,5\}&(6,15,3)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{10,10\}&(2,10,2)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{12,3\}&(24,36,6)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{12,4\}&(9,18,3)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{12,6\}&(4,12,2)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{15,3\}&(20,30,4)&\\
\cline{2-3}
&   \{16,4\}&(8,16,2)&\\
\cline{2-4}
&   \{16,16\}&(1,8,1)&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{FP}\\
\cline{2-4}
&   \{18,3\}&(18,27,3)&\\
\cline{2-4}
&   \{18,9\}&(2,9,1)&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{FP}\\
\cline{2-4}
&   \{24,3\}&(16,24,2)&\\
\cline{2-4}
&   \{28,4\}&(7,14,1)&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{FP}\\
\cline{2-4}
&   \{42,3\}&(14,21,1)&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{FP}\\
\cline{2-4}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

As alternative is table without vertical rules and with horizontal rules from package `booktabs`. Last part of such designed table is:

[image]

and MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{longtable}{>{\hphantom{FP}}c>{$}c<{$}>{$}c<{$}c}
    \caption{Caption1}\\
\cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-3}
&    \mathbf{\{p,q\}}&\mathbf{(V,E,F)}&     \\
 \cmidrule[0.4pt]{2-3}
\endfirsthead
   \caption{caption2}\\
\cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-3}
&    \mathbf{\{p,q\}}&\mathbf{(V,E,F)}&~\\
\cmidrule[0.4pt]{2-3}
\endhead
&   \{3,7\}&(36,126,84)&\\
&   \{3,8\}&(18,72,48)&\\
&   \{3,9\}&(12,54,36)&\\
&   \{3,10\}&(9,45,30)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{3,12\}&(6,36,24)&\\
&   \{3,15\}&(4,30,20)&\\
&   \{3,18\}&(3,27,18)&\\
&   \{3,24\}&(2,24,16)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{3,42\}&(1,21,14)&\\
&   \{4,5\}&(24,60,30)&\\
&   \{4,6\}&(12,36,18)&\\
&   \{4,7\}&(8,28,14)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{4,8\}&(6,24,12)&\\
&   \{4,10\}&(4,20,10)&\\
&   \{4,12\}&(3,18,9)&\\
&   \{4,16\}&(2,16,8)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{4,28\}&(1,14,7)&\\
&   \{5,4\}&(30,60,24)&\\
&   \{5,5\}&(12,30,12)&\\
&   \{5,10\}&(3,15,6)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{6,4\}&(18,36,12)&\\
&   \{6,6\}&(6,18,6)&\\
&   \{6,12\}&(2,12,4)&\\
&   \{7,3\}&(84,126,36)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{7,4\}&(14,28,8)&\\
&   \{7,7\}&(4,14,4)&\\
&   \{8,3\}&(48,72,18)&\\
&   \{8,4\}&(12,24,6)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{8,8\}&(3,12,3)&\\
&   \{9,3\}&(36,54,12)&\\
&   \{9,18\}&(1,9,2)&\\
&   \{10,3\}&(30,45,9)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{10,4\}&(10,20,4)&\\
&   \{10,5\}&(6,15,3)&\\
&   \{10,10\}&(2,10,2)&\\
&   \{12,3\}&(24,36,6)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{12,4\}&(9,18,3)&\\
&   \{12,6\}&(4,12,2)&\\
&   \{15,3\}&(20,30,4)&\\
&   \{16,4\}&(8,16,2)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{16,16\}&(1,8,1)& {FP}\\
&   \{18,3\}&(18,27,3)&\\
&   \{18,9\}&(2,9,1) & {FP}\\
&   \{24,3\}&(16,24,2)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{28,4\}&(7,14,1)& {FP}\\
&   \{42,3\}&(14,21,1)& {FP}\\
\cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-3}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I would rather check if this this long table split into two half and positioned in parallel can fit on one page:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
    \caption{Caption1}
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\hphantom{FP}}c>{$}c<{$}>{$}c<{$}c}
    \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-3}
&    \mathbf{\{p,q\}}&\mathbf{(V,E,F)}&     \\
    \cmidrule[0.4pt]{2-3}
&   \{3,7\}&(36,126,84)&\\
&   \{3,8\}&(18,72,48)&\\
&   \{3,9\}&(12,54,36)&\\
&   \{3,10\}&(9,45,30)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{3,12\}&(6,36,24)&\\
&   \{3,15\}&(4,30,20)&\\
&   \{3,18\}&(3,27,18)&\\
&   \{3,24\}&(2,24,16)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{3,42\}&(1,21,14)&\\
&   \{4,5\}&(24,60,30)&\\
&   \{4,6\}&(12,36,18)&\\
&   \{4,7\}&(8,28,14)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{4,8\}&(6,24,12)&\\
&   \{4,10\}&(4,20,10)&\\
&   \{4,12\}&(3,18,9)&\\
&   \{4,16\}&(2,16,8)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{4,28\}&(1,14,7)&\\
&   \{5,4\}&(30,60,24)&\\
&   \{5,5\}&(12,30,12)&\\
&   \{5,10\}&(3,15,6)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{6,4\}&(18,36,12)&\\
&   \{6,6\}&(6,18,6)&\\
&   \{6,12\}&(2,12,4)&\\
&   \{7,3\}&(84,126,36)&\\
    \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-3}
\end{tabular}%
\quad% space between tables
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\hphantom{FP}}c>{$}c<{$}>{$}c<{$}c}
    \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-3}
&    \mathbf{\{p,q\}}&\mathbf{(V,E,F)}&     \\
    \cmidrule[0.4pt]{2-3}
&   \{7,4\}&(14,28,8)&\\
&   \{7,7\}&(4,14,4)&\\
&   \{8,3\}&(48,72,18)&\\
&   \{8,4\}&(12,24,6)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{8,8\}&(3,12,3)&\\
&   \{9,3\}&(36,54,12)&\\
&   \{9,18\}&(1,9,2)&\\
&   \{10,3\}&(30,45,9)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{10,4\}&(10,20,4)&\\
&   \{10,5\}&(6,15,3)&\\
&   \{10,10\}&(2,10,2)&\\
&   \{12,3\}&(24,36,6)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{12,4\}&(9,18,3)&\\
&   \{12,6\}&(4,12,2)&\\
&   \{15,3\}&(20,30,4)&\\
&   \{16,4\}&(8,16,2)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{16,16\}&(1,8,1)& {FP}\\
&   \{18,3\}&(18,27,3)&\\
&   \{18,9\}&(2,9,1) & {FP}\\
&   \{24,3\}&(16,24,2)&\\
\addlinespace
&   \{28,4\}&(7,14,1)& {FP}\\
&   \{42,3\}&(14,21,1)& {FP}\\
%&           &           &       \\
%&           &           &       \\
\cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-3}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Two questions arise: **1)** Where does `\hphantom` come from? `array`, `longtable` or standard LaTeX?     **2)** How does `booktabs` center the table? I.e. how do I control its centering behaviour?

Comment: (i) `hphantom{...}` is defined in LaTeX kernel , (ii) `booktabs` doesn't center anything.  for last example should be present `\centering`, which is (I see now, corrected) accidentally erased.

Answer (score 1):

Here I introduce `\fauxcol` that one actually uses at the end of the column 2 data.  It assumes certain things:

1. `\tabcolsep` column separation is in force,
2. all table data has the vertical footprint of a `\strut`.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\def\fauxcol#1{\unskip\smash{\rlap{\fboxsep=0pt\relax\hspace{\tabcolsep}\fbox{%
  \hspace{\tabcolsep}#1\strut\hspace{\tabcolsep}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Two-column table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
the & end\\
\hline
x & y\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Extra faux column}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
the & end\fauxcol{FP}\\
\hline
x & y\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]